# Changing counters across and within sections

Tags: numbering, counters, gb4e, chngcntr

I am making a document with glosses (using package `gb4e`) and sections. The glosses correspond to certain numbers within certain chapters, but these chapters do not correspond to the sections I'm using; those depend on a certain date. See the MWE.

How can I reset the glosses counter at places of my own liking. Until now I used the `chngcntr` package with the command `\counterwithin{exx}{section}`, but when the sections and 'chapters' (when the counter has to be reset) do not correspond, I'm getting into trouble.

Using a `\section*` does not work, since the counter continues.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{exx}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Yesterday}
\begin{center}{\scshape\large Chapter 1}\end{center}
\begin{exe} 
\ex \gll This is a sentence we read yesterday\\
Este es una frase [nos] leer ayer\\

\section{Today}                
\ex \gll This way the counter continues, but it isn't preferable either\\
Este manera el contador continuar, pero lo no.es preferible tampoco\\
\end{exe}

\begin{center}{\scshape\large Chapter 2}\end{center}
\begin{exe} 
\ex \gll This.one should.be number 1 again\\
Este ser\'{i}a numero 1 de.nuevo\\ 
\end{exe}

\section{Tomorrow}
\begin{exe}
\ex \gll I want this to be number 2.\\
[yo] quere este a ser numero 2\\

\begin{center}{\scshape\large Chapter 3}\end{center}
\ex \gll And this is a 1.\\
Eta hau da bat 1\\
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the `\counterwithin{exx}{section}` is not at all handy here, but the first times the chapters and dates more or less corresponded.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. You can say `\setcounter{exx}{0}` at appropriate points and that will reset the counter provided, I think, you are not in the middle of an `exe` environment where it seems to have no effect. But I don't understand what you are doing with the fake chapters and sectioning. What is not preferable? Why not use real chapters? Why start a chapter within a section? I basically get a mess and I have very little idea how to clean it up.

Comment: Well, that is maybe not what I thought to be needed, but it really solves the problem. I didn't thought it was that simple.

Comment: @jopie: I've added another (possible) solution some days ago. Could you give some feedback, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange fact that faked chapters come in between sections does not simplify the whole procedure.

I my opinion, the `\section` command should **not** start within an `exe` environment. Doing this, a macro `\centredchapter` with automatic titles and counting does the job, if `\counterwithin{exx}{chapter}` is used.

A reset via `\setcounter{exx}{0}` where appropiate can done anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newcounter{chapter}
\counterwithin{exx}{chapter}


\newcommand{\centredchapter}{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \begin{center}\scshape\large Chapter~\thechapter\end{center}
}%


\begin{document}

\section{Yesterday}
\centredchapter
%\begin{center}{\scshape\large Chapter 1}\end{center}
\begin{exe} 
\ex \gll This is a sentence we read yesterday\\
Este es una frase [nos] leer ayer\\
\end{exe}
\section{Today}                
\begin{exe}
\ex \gll This way the counter continues, but it isn't preferable either\\
Este manera el contador continuar, pero lo no.es preferible tampoco\\
\end{exe}
\centredchapter
%\begin{center}{\scshape\large Chapter 2}\end{center}
\begin{exe} 
\ex \gll This.one should.be number 1 again\\
Este ser\'{i}a numero 1 de.nuevo\\ 
\end{exe}

\section{Tomorrow}
\begin{exe}
\ex \gll I want this to be number 2.\\
[yo] quere este a ser numero 2\\
\end{exe}
\centredchapter
\begin{exe}
\ex \gll And this is a 1.\\
Eta hau da bat 1\\
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image]